# Linq ToDictionary Not Defined?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have this code

```
var contacts = dr.mktDoctorContacts
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContactType)
    .Select(zb => new 
     { 
         Key = zb.Key,
         GroupWiseContacts = zb.Select(x => x.Contact).ToList()
     })
    .ToDictionary<string,List<string>>(y => y.Key, y => y.GroupWiseContacts)
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code.

Compile time error msg says:System.Generic.IEnumerable does not contain definition of and best extension method overloads has some invalid arguments. i can see only two overloads of ToDictionary Method in my visual studio tooltip sort of documentation whereas i have come across more than two overloads of ToDictionary on the web

**Edit** Here is exact Error message at compile time

> Error 13  '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   '`ToDictionary`' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   '`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   System.Func<TSource,TKey>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TKey>)`'
>   has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Lazarus it was a typo. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Can you please update your question with the *exact* error message you are receiving? What you have included seems to be only half the error.

Comment: @Programming Hero updated the question. plz have a look

Comment: @Muhammad Try deleting the `<string,List<string>>`. The compiler will infer automatically the types of ToDictionary.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The compiler message makes the error clear: There is no method `ToDictionary` which can accept the arguments and types specified.

The mistake here is in specifying the type arguments on `ToDictionary`. The MSDN documentation defines the extension method as [`ToDictionary<TKey, TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx). The source in your example is `IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`, but you have specified a type of `List<string>`.

To correct the error, omit the type arguments; the compiler will infer the correct types. You can additionally combine the `Select` and `ToDictionary` transformations into a single statement:

```
var contacts = dr.mktDoctorContacts
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContactType)
    .ToDictionary(
        y => y.Key, 
        y => y.Select(x => x.Contact).ToList());
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out that one. i mistakenly considered it to be ToDictionary<TKey, TElement>.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote your code (and added `.AsEnumerable()`):

```
var dictionary = dr.mktDoctorContacts
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContactType)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(
        i => i.Key, 
        i => i.Select(x => x.Contact).ToList()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't run that group operation in the database, it'll cause the elements of each group to be fetched in separate roundtrips.

```
ILookup<string, string> contacts = dr.mktDoctorContacts
  .ToLookup<Contact, string, string>(x => x.ContactType, x => x.Contact);
```