# C# Convert a List to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to convert a `List<Ctrl>` to a `Dictionary<string, Ctrl>` using `Ctrl.Name` as the key. I've referenced this page to attempt to achieve this: [Microsoft's Enumerable.ToDictionary Method page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0)

Hence, my code looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Ctrl> oActionControls;

oActionControls = (from ctrl in _ctrls.Items
                   where ctrl.CtrlTypeCode == "BUTTON"
                   orderby ctrl.TabIndex
                   select ctrl).ToList().ToDictionary<string, Ctrl>(a => a, b => b.Name);
```

I get an error on `ToDictionary<string, Ctrl>(a => a, b => b.Name)` which reads:
*Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AppData.Ctrl>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'*

*Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AppData.Ctrl>'*

*Argument 2: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<string,AppData.Ctrl>'*

*'System.Collections.Generic.List<AppData.Ctrl>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDictionary' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid arguments*

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. Also, it seems strange to me that a Dictionary is declared in the order `<key, value>` and the ToDictionary constructor takes the lambda functions in the order `<value, key>`.

How do I fix this? I'm a bit lost. Thanks.

Edit:
Added to list, and included all the compiletime errors.

Edit 2:
Removed the type arguments for ToDictionary. I've also removed the ToList() call which is superflous, so that the code reads:

```
oActionControls = (from ctrl in _ctrls.Items
                   where ctrl.CtrlTypeCode == "BUTTON"
                   orderby ctrl.TabIndex
                   select ctrl).ToDictionary(a => a.Name);
```

which works correctly.

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq;` in your code?

Comment: `.ToDictionary<string, Ctrl>(b => b.Name, b => b);`?

Comment: No, ```System.Linq``` is in there. The error is on ```ToList().ToDictionary<string, Ctrl>(a => a, b => b.Name)``` not on the Linq statement.

Comment: The key in your dictionary is a string and the value the control but your ToDictionary call does it the other way around.

Comment: Oh also you have the lambda expressions the wrong way round: `.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, b => b)` (note you don't need to specify the generic types since they can be inferred.

Comment: @Link and DavidG - neither of these. I've tried both and various other combinations. Microsoft's example in the link has a single lambda function which maps to the key value, which I've also tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104509/linq-todictionary-not-defined it might be a description of your problem

Comment: It clearly does work fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vnzmv

Comment: If you want to specify full description of a function of ToDictionary, then you should use ToDictionary<Ctrl, string, Ctrl>in you case.

Comment: @DavidG - I'd included <string, Ctrl> in the call to ToDictionary. It was this that was causing the issue. Have modified the text above to reflect this. Useful website though - thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a `List<Ctrl>`, you could create the dictionary simply by calling `.ToDictionary()` with a key selector parameter (see [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)):

```
Dictionary<string, Ctrl> actionControls = ctrls.ToDictionary(ctrl => ctrl.Name);
```

Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;` statement.

Also - a dictionary does not have an order, so you could remove the `order by` clause from the query.

Verifyable example:

```
var ctrls = new List<Ctrl>
{
    new Ctrl { CtrlTypeCode = "1", Name = "My value 1" },
    new Ctrl { CtrlTypeCode = "2", Name = "My value 2" },
    new Ctrl { CtrlTypeCode = "3", Name = "My value 3" },
};
Dictionary<string, Ctrl> actionControls = ctrls.ToDictionary(ctrl => ctrl.Name);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Class2
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
    }
```

```
    List<Class2> list = new List<Class2>();
    Class2 c1 = new Class2();
    c1.name = "Tom";
    c1.age = 15;
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.name = "Ada";
    c2.age = 17;
    list.Add(c1);
    list.Add(c2);
    Dictionary<string, Class2> dict = new Dictionary<string, Class2>();
    dict = list.ToDictionary(b => b.name);
```